# bulk_update_mappings by field which is different than private key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class with db fields

```py
id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True) 
uuid = db.Column(
  UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=True, default=uuid.uuid4
) 
name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

And then I wanted to bulk update by 'uuid' field, not id as by default:

```py
updates = []
for upd in body['new_data']:
    update = {
        'uuid': upd['uuid'],
        'name': upd['name'],
    }
    updates.append(update)

db.session.bulk_update_mappings(MyClass, updates)
```

But I have an error that there are no matches. How can I do bulk update by 'uuid' field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official SQLAlchemy documentation, it will not be possible.

> All those keys which are present and are not part of the primary key
>   are applied to the SET clause of the UPDATE statement; the primary key
>   values, which are required, are applied to the WHERE clause.

*source: [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_update_mappings)*

If you want an alternative, try using `on_conflict_do_update()` which works like 
an upsert, and you can specify on which column should be the `where` clause done.

[Here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.on_conflict_do_update.params.index_elements) is the documentation explaining how it works in detail.

Comment: `on_conflict_do_update` 's `set_` parameter accepts a `dict`, not an iterable, so how does it help with bulk updates?